# I am try to call BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback but it callback is not called . it is not work

Tags: android, bluetooth

Here is my code which is I am using.
I am trying to call BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback but it callback is not called. it is not work 
I have declared the permission on Manifest file BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN as well as the CROSS_LOCATION permission.

```
 // Oncreate method
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mHandler = new Handler();
            CheckPermission();

  //check here for device supoort the BLE 
   if(!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your device is not supported the Bluetooth features",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }

                bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
                mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

                if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("the device not enable");
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                }
        }

 // OnActivityResult method 
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode==REQUEST_ENABLE_LOCATION)
        {
            System.out.println("the requent granted");
        }
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scanLeDevice(false);
        mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
    }
     // Here it is function to start the scan for search the BEL device.
     private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {

        try {

            if (enable) {
                // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mScanning = false;
                        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }
                }, SCAN_PERIOD);
                mScanning = true;
                mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                System.out.println("the start le can called");

            } else {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

            }
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"startLecan error "+e);
        }
    }

       // this callback is not called.
       public BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                System.out.println("the callback is called ");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"the callback is called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                                mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                            catch (Exception is )
                            {
                                System.out.println("the exception is callback "+is);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

        @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }
        // Initializes list view adapter.
        mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }
```

Here is my logcat:

```
07-22 10:43:42.610 8400-8400/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
07-22 10:43:42.814 8400-8400/app.com.bluetoothreadydemo W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-22 10:43:43.083 8400-8400/app.com.bluetoothreadydemo I/System.out: the start le scan 
07-22 10:43:43.105 8400-8417/app.com.bluetoothreadydemo D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
07-22 10:43:43.149 8400-8482/app.com.bluetoothreadydemo D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
07-22 10:43:43.156 8400-8400/app.com.bluetoothreadydemo D/Atlas: Validating map...
07-22 10:43:43.232 8400-8400/app.com.bluetoothreadydemo V/PhoneWindow: updateColorViewInt()if drawable=null color=-13615201
07-22 10:43:43.236 8400-8482/app.com.bluetoothreadydemo I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.2.1_RB1.05.00.02.033.013_msm8916_64_LA.BR.1.2.1_RB1__release_AU ()
                                                                      OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
                                                                      Build Date: 04/22/15 Wed
                                                                      Local Branch: mybranch9281365
                                                                      Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.2.1_rb1.14
                                                                      Local Patches: NONE
                                                                      Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.2.1_RB1.05.00.02.033.013 + fe3456f + b3003f0 + 5175e13 + ea63815 + 8dbff94 + 85ec7ec + 27616ec +  NOTHING
07-22 10:43:43.236 8400-8482/app.com.bluetoothreadydemo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-22 10:43:43.248 8400-8482/app.com.bluetoothreadydemo D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
07-22 10:43:43.390 8400-8400/app.com.bluetoothreadydemo I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1d27e98b time:2540054
```

Comment: Did you have peripheral device around? did you get the btsnoop log? and logcat log?

Comment: Yes. I have two Android devices. I start the Bluetooth on it after run my app but I can not found both devices in an app.

Comment: When I run the app BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback does not call not display the Toast message inside the callback.

Comment: I mean did your mobile device searched the peripheral? You can observer your btsnoop log to see where the message blocked.

Comment: above is my logcat print.

Comment: I did not see the log of "the start le can called"